Resuming hourly recurring scheduled job causes job to trigger every minute
I have a job chain in prod to fetch data from an outsource.
Since we have multiple data source for different reasons we have chain batchs. Which means we call series of batches one by one in hourly rate.
However sometimes for other migration purposes I have to pause this hourly scheduled job to perform my other data migration. When I come back to resume the job, resuming action crushed and triggers hourly job in every minute.
Since this batch chain has more than 5 batches which are using callouts with pagination logic, the bug causes a crash by hitting 100 apex queue governor limit.
My question is why simple resume button causing crush?
Is this something I can solve or it is only solvable by a salesforce ticket?

Clicking Manage and rescheduling with the same cron expression solved the problem.
